# What are the ways to share data from an app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to create a camera application.

What are the available ways to share photos that were taken from my app? Email a photo? Send it via bluetooth? Probably a user can upload it to his computer?
How can I implement them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send your photo by e-mail, you must save it into a file, create a new mail and attach the picture.

To send it via bluetooth, you must use GameKit or Bonjour protocols to connect to other devices and exchange data using your own application protocol.

To upload to his computer, you must use a Wi-Fi network protocol, and implement a client and server.

Good luck!